# Converting json object to two arrays using java

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

Hello is there a way I can convert this json object into two arrays ? I have tried the code below and it works fine, But am failing to convert the json object into two arrays one called 'id' and the other array called 'name'. How can I go about this. this is how far I have gone

```
 int[] id= {};
 String[] names={};

myfunction = new myFunctions();
    json = userfunction.petitions();

    try {
        if (json.get(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
            String rs = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
            if (Integer.parseInt(rs) == 1) {
                inserting ids into id array here....
                inserting names into names array here..
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and the json object is

```
10-25 02:08:54.325: E/JSON(406): {"success":1,"petitions":[{"id":"1","name":"Has        Jennifer Musisi done great work for Kampala","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:32:58"},{"id":"2","name":"Do lecturers deserve 100% salary increase","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:32:58"},{"id":"3","name":"Olara Otunu should get married","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"},{"id":"4","name":"Teachers deserve 30 not 20 salary rise","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"},{"id":"5","name":"Prostitution should be banned","timestamp":"2013-10-24 14:33:53"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`petitions` is a JSON array so you can create a JSONArray object, catch the values, and then get the strings from the array.

For example:

```
id[0] = myArray[0].getString("id");
names[0] = myArray[0].getString("names");
```

Just throw that in a for loop for `myArray.length()`

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONArray jar=json.getJSONArray("petitions");
 int len=jar.length();
for(int ctr=0;ctr<len;ctr++)
{
 JSONObject job =  jar.getI(ctr);   


}
```

hope this helps.